# How to search between two dates in a text file??? HASH MAP?

Tags: java, file, text, hashmap

For example I have the following file

```
B 01-02-2013 1233 
B 03-02-2013 129
B 04-02-2013 13
```

the date is stored as a String from user input. The next number is a integer for "CaloriesBurnt"

I want to if given a start date and end date. CALCULATE TOTAL CALORIES BURNED between those two dates. So for example here I would want to total the calories from 01-02-2013 TO 04-02-2013. So i need to pull the calories for the dates inbetween that period. I Know I have to convert to date format and then perhaps use a HASP MAP? to order?? any help really is appreciated

Comment: There are several different ways to do this - one of the ways is to get the ms of the date (getTime() method if I am not mistaken), and then go through all the dates, get the ms of that date, and check if it is in the interval. If you are going to perform this calculation more than once, then you need to store that in some data structure that makes things easier for you - I don't think a HashMap is the more appropriated data structure. Maybe a sorted list is the best thing for you to use.

Comment: Is it certain that the start/ finish dates will also be dates in your input? If that is not the case, then I think a map might really not be the adequate data choice.

Answer (score 4):

The best data structure in that situation is a TreeMap. It maintains its keys sorted, and has [methods returning a "submap"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#subMap%28K,%20boolean,%20K,%20boolean%29) containing all the entries between two key values.

If each date is unique, you can use a `TreeMap<Date, Record>`. If not, then use a `TreeMap<Date, List<Record>>` (Record being the class used to hold all the elements of one line of your file).

Once you have the submap, you just need to iterate on all the values and sum their calories.

Comment: JB I had to test this. I didn't know sorted maps behave like that.

Answer (score 1):

You might probably want to use a sorted collection like a `SortedMap<Date, UserData>` ( `UserData` would represent whatever data you want to store in the map), then use `subMap(startDate, endDate + 1 day)` to extract period. Note that `endDate + 1 day` is needed since the upper bound is exclusive.

Example:

```
SortedMap<Date, Integer> caloriesByDate = new TreeMap<>(); //we only store the calories

... //fill here

SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
//get entries in the interval `[01-02-2013,03-02-2013]`.
caloriesByDate.subMap( f.parse("01-02-2013"), f.parse("04-02-2013") );
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would parse the whole text file into objects. No matter how the date is. Each line in the text file could be something like this (of course with setters and getters and public/private and all this stuff ;):

```
class Entry {
    Date date;
    int calories;
}
```

Parse the text file and create a list of such objects. Then you could operate on this list. You can sort it (with a sorter-object written by you), you can search it or do what ever you want. Once you get rid of the actual text file and you have objects, it gets much easier. You can even use some third-party libraries to easily compute statistics (e.g. the average, max values or such things).